# How do I view activity bar in visual studio? I've reinstalled it and every time it's not viewable

Tags: visual-studio-2019

before you say "just go to view > appearance >

[image]

The Activity bar just isn't visible on the left where it should be. I've searched everywhere and it simply isnt anywhere to be found unless i missed something. I've tried ,ctrl shift p then searching for it. still nothing. I've tried going to view > appearance > then toggle activity bar, but when i click view, appearance isnt even an option.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the stack overflow. Your question doesn't belong here. It's more of a question that should be asked to the Visual Studio forum/support.

Comment: It is Visual Studio Code that has Activity bar https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface So you should install it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Select View → Appearance → Hide/Show Activity Bar.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I can't do that. Look at the screenshot and you'll see that when I go to view, appearance isn't available in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I think you wanted to download "Visual Studio Code", your view drop down looks like "visual studio". I guess the sidebar you want is only in "visual studio code". I also was confusted once. Hope I could help you!